# Type declarations syntax difference between haskell and haskell-like language

Tags: haskell, syntax

In Haskell, type declarations using double colon i.e. (::), like `not :: Bool -> Bool`.

But in many languages whose syntax is similar to Haskell, e.g. elm, agda,
they use single colon (:) to declare type. like `not : Bool -> Bool`.

Why these languages abandoned the haskell style type declaration syntax.

- is (:) better than (::) to declare a type?
- Or is (::) more suitable for other uses ?
- Or just because (:) is one char less than (::) ?

Comment: FWIW, I consider `::` to actually read more nicely in a top-level signature, as it brings a bit more space between the value level and the type level. `not : Bool -> Bool` looks a bit like it should be parsed `(not : Bool) -> Bool`. But many existing infix operators have much the same issue; I suppose it basically just matters what you're used to.

Comment: If you pretend that a type annotation is an actual value, `::` makes a kind of sense. It starts with a `:` like any other infix constructor, it precedes the "real" symbol for type annotations, and given a name and a type as arguments it returns a type annotation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I heard SPJ say somewhere that it was a debated issue to choose
between `:` and `::`. He and John Hughes finally settled on `::`. From
the [A History of Haskell: Being Lazy With
Class](http://haskell.cs.yale.edu/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/history.pdf) paper:

> We adopted from Miranda the convention that data constructors are
>   capitalised while variables are not, and added a similar convention
>   for infix constructors, which in Haskell must start with a colon. The
>   latter convention was chosen for consistency with our use (adopted
>   from SASL, KRC, and Miranda) of a single colon : for the list “cons”
>   operator.  (The choice of “ : ” for cons and “ :: ” for type
>   signatures, by the way, was a hotly contested issue (ML does the
>   opposite) and remains controversial to this day.)

Comment: I don't think it was SPJ and John Hughes who decided this.  Initially it was Phil Wadler's design (mimicking Miranda and Orwell), and then the Haskell committee kept it.  It was an unfortunate choice.

Comment: Yeah, I think it was between SPJ and Wadler. I will probably try to link the video by the weekend.

Answer (score 12):

IIRC the Haskell choice of using `::` is a bit of an (unfortunate) historical accident. Haskell was based largely off of Miranda, which also uses `::` for types<sup>1</sup>. The authors of Miranda really wanted the cons operator to be `:` since they thought it would used much more ubiquitously, so the typing operator had to be delegated to `::`.

It really hasn't proved to be a good idea since otherwise all the literature (even that which talks about Haskell) on types uses `:`. As the nearest [paper at hand](https://www.seas.upenn.edu/~sweirich/papers/type-app-extended.pdf), the double colon is used for all sample (Haskell) code, yet the mathematical judgements (like on page 10) all follow the traditional single colon.

---

<sup>1</sup> I think I remember hearing somewhere (EDIT: it was [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hIZxTQP1ifo), but I'm too lazy to listen to the whole thing to get the right time) that, at the time, a lot of FP research people just wanted to define Miranda very clearly so that research papers talking about lazy-functional-pure languages could have a common language to talk about their ideas. The designers of Miranda didn't want this, but instead said they'd be fine if this was done with another language which could be quite similar to Miranda (provided, for the benefit of both parties, that the two languages still be distinguishable). That was the starting point for the Haskell committee.

Comment: I wouldn't call it _that_ unfortunate. Reversing them would've probably been better, but it's hardly the end of the world that the haskell notation is slightly different from the common math notation (this is the case in many other places than types as well).

Comment: Your footnote is not entirely accurate.